# Google map loads static image

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-app-engine, google-maps-api-3

I am using `google map API` in my project. My code is :

```
var map;
var op = {
   zoom: 8,
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("container"), op);
```

My problem is that google loads a static image instead of an interactive map. I also tried

`useStaticMap: false` in options but after using this it loads nothing, (no map, no image).

Please tell me whats going on here?

Comment: If you provide a link to your full code or put it up on jsFiddle then we can debug it. Otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: Actually my javascript code is too long and this is a part of it, i am providing a facility to my user to add map. So i am just taking the input from the user ( a city name and using geocoding i will get the latlag ) but currently i am hardcode this latlan from the example. So when user click the add map button this function is called and map is added. But a static and i want interactive

Comment: So it shouldn't be giving you static only with the code you've shown us. Therefore it is something happening on the rest of the page. Maybe you can excerpt a portion of the code that demonstrates the problem and post that. Otherwise you're asking us to debug something we can't see since the portion you posted looks right. And I won't do that.

Answer (score 2):

When you say static map does that mean that you can't zoom, pan, etc.  It's been a while since I worked with Google Maps, but as I recall you can provide settings that would enable the zooming and panning.  Try enabling those features as opposed to using the static map.  Or conversely maybe you have disabled them.

I guess it could also be the javasscript file that you are including.  Also, there are two API's and it seems like you can have two different API keys.  Maybe you have the static one.  So there are about three different options there.  Most likely one of those is the issue because the code is very small and looks well formed to me.

**API v3**

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

**Static Maps**

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

I would try adding a control.  Or maybe giving us a little more of your code.

Adding Controls to the Map

You may wish to tailor your interface by removing, adding, or modifying UI behavior or controls and ensure that future updates don't alter this behavior. If you wish to only add or modify existing behavior, you need to ensure that the control is explicitly added to your application.

Some controls appear on the map by default while others will not appear unless you specifically request them. Adding or removing controls from the map is specified in the following Map options object's fields, which you set to true to make them visible or set to false to hide them:

```
{
  panControl: boolean,
  zoomControl: boolean,
  mapTypeControl: boolean,
  scaleControl: boolean,
  streetViewControl: boolean,
  overviewMapControl: boolean
}
```

The following example sets the map to hide the navigation (Zoom and Pan) controls and display the scale control. Note that we do not explicitly disable the default UI, so these modifications are additive to the default UI behavior.

```
function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
    panControl: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    scaleControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
}
```

Here is the reference to the code.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls

Comment: If i am not wrong the person who voted you down want to tell you that this is not a place to write story or novel kind of things. Don`t mind just answer your question :)

Comment: He provided 7 lines of code that are well formed so while it appears I am taking a shot in the dark, in reality there isn't much information to go on, not to mention that I am trying to help. If he wants the answer on a silver platter I don't think I should get voted down for that.  Did I write a novel?  Either way how about not being so damn rude, especially when you are asking for help.  Where the love, where's manners.

Answer (score 2):

150.644, -34.397, this coordinate doesn't exists

Comment: The original post has -34.397, 150.644, which is correct. @wavedrop, latitude must come first for a LatLng object. Latitude goes from -90 to 90, so having it the way Damax posted would be Longitude/Latitude.